# (MySQL) JOIN a table with individual date AND another with date range

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join, date-range

I am new to SQL and am trying to join 2 tables on MySQL: one with a date and another with date range.

**Table 1 contains:**

```
Service date (e.g. 2017-01-01)
 Vendor City 
 Vendor ID
 Vendor Name
 Sales
```

**Table 2 contains:**

```
Special Date ID
 Special Date Description
 Special Date range from (e.g. 2016-12-30)
 Special Date range to  (e.g. 2016-01-03)
 Vendor City
 Vendor ID
```

I **want to left join these two tables where the service date is between the special date range.**

Would anyone can suggest good SQL statement for using above example?

Thank you,

Comment: I want to know what is your try? why should we suggest? this is not freelancing site.

Comment: your column_name shouldn't have space between words

Comment: Hi Pathik, thanks for the comments. I tried using an ETL tool but was unable to do these kinds of join. I remind myself to avoid space for the colum names.

Answer (score 1):

Use `between` or inequalities:

```
select . . .
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.service_date between t2.start_date and t2.end_date;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thank you very much for your quick answer!